# About Apache Cordova Setup

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle

[image: REQUIREMENTS]

[image: TERMINAL IMG WITH ERROR]

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2846]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Tüm hakları saklıdır.

C:\Users\acer>cordova create demo com.dynm.demo demo
Creating a new cordova project.

C:\Users\acer>cd demo

C:\Users\acer\demo>cordova platform add android
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
Path: platforms\android
Package: com.dynm.demo
Name: demo
Activity: MainActivity
Android Target SDK: android-33
Android Compile SDK: 33
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Android project created with cordova-android@12.0.0

C:\Users\acer\demo>cordova build
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Welcome to Gradle 7.4.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:

- Aggregated test and JaCoCo reports
- Marking additional test source directories as tests in IntelliJ
- Support for Adoptium JDKs in Java toolchains

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.1/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BU¦LD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'demo'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
> Required by:
> project :
> > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BU¦LD FAILED in 6s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\acer\demo\platforms\android\gradlew -b C:\Users\acer\demo\platforms\android\build.gradle cdvBuildDebug

C:\Users\acer\demo>cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
Command failed with exit code 1: avdmanager list target
'avdmanager' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Gradle: installed C:\gradle-7.4.1\bin\gradle.BAT
Some of requirements check failed

How can ı slow this problem?